# Entity Framework and timespan computation

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework

How do I get persons whose age is over 21 using EF?

```
from person in context.Persons
where DateTime.UtcNow - person.Dob > TimeSpan.FromHours(184086)
select new {person, Age = DateTime.UtcNow - person.Dob}
```

The above failed.

What can I do to fix this? Is the above supported in the more recent version of EF eg. 4.2+

Can I access the properties of the DateTime struct as follow?

```
from person in context.Persons
where DateTime.UtcNow.Year - person.Dob.Year > 21
select new {person, Age = DateTime.UtcNow.Year - person.Dob.Year}
```

Comment: "The above failed." How did it fail? Error message? Incorrect result?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the `<` operator in linq-to-entites queries. You can't use addition or subtraction though. Fortunately, [`SqlFunctions`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.objects.sqlclient.sqlfunctions.aspx) has functions to calculate date differences. So what you can do is this:

```
var d21 = DateTime.Today.AddYears(-21);
var q = from person in context.Persons
        where person.Dob < d21
        select new
        {
            person,
            Age = SqlFunctions.DateDiff("year", person.Dob, DateTime.Today)
        }
```

You have to create the variable `d21` first, otherwise EF complains about not knowing `AddYears`.

Comment: Ouch, that's complicated for something that should be simple.

Comment: Yes, linq-to-sql does handle date addition/subtraction but it generates monsters of sql expressions that may have the potential of knocking down performance. SqlFunctions use database functions in stead.

Comment: Didn't know about the existence of SqlFunctions. Thank you Gert for enlightenment.